# CloudBees - dependency between parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

I'm currently developing a template and in the groovy template transformation I'm defining some parameters for the jobs that will be using this template.

My problem is: I have one parameter (A) that depends on another parameter (B). Is there any way to refresh the parameter A when parameter B changes?

Thank you.